# Is it appropriate to use the Decorator Pattern while extending RecyclerView.Adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've written a `FooterAdapter` that seems to work perfectly.

I realised the `ViewHolder` has a field `mPosition` among others that hold state in each element leading me to suspect that a Header is not achievable by usage of the Decorator Pattern, because it would hold a different position in each `Adapter`.

That is, except if the wrapper/decorator `Adapter` didn't alter the other elements. That is to say: footers are OK, as long as data does not need to be binded to them.

If Wrapper adapters were possible then we would need more access to ViewHolder? I'm not sure how the fields

Intended Usage:

```
headerView = new View( context );
footerView = new View( context );

MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
HeaderAdapter headerAdapter = new HeaderAdapter( myAdapter , headerView );
FooterAdapter footerAdapter = new FooterAdapter( headerAdapter , footerView );

RecyclerView recyclerView = new RecyclerView();
recyclerView.setAdapter( footerAdapter );
```

This would be really cool, because then we could add headers & footers to any arbitrary `Adapter` and not have to worry about indexing and offsetting item counts.

FooterAdapter.java

```
public class FooterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private static final String TAG = "FooterAdapter";
    private final RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> wrappedAdapter;

    private View footer;

    public static final int FOOTER_TYPE = 0x72846fe;

    public FooterAdapter( RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> wrappedAdapter , View footer )
    {
        this.footer = footer;
        this.wrappedAdapter = wrappedAdapter;
        wrappedAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new ThisObserver());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        if( position == wrappedAdapter.getItemCount() ) return FOOTER_TYPE;
        return wrappedAdapter.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if( viewType == FOOTER_TYPE )
        {
            return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder( footer ){};
        }else
        {
            return wrappedAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(parent,viewType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if( holder.getItemViewType() == FOOTER_TYPE ) return;
        return wrappedAdapter.bindViewHolder( holder , position );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return wrappedAdapter.getItemCount() + 1;
    }


    private class ThisObserver extends AdapterDataObserver
    {
        public void onChanged() {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart,itemCount);
        }

        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart,itemCount);
        }

        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(positionStart,itemCount);
        }

        public void onItemRangeMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount) {
            int lower = Math.min( fromPosition , toPosition );
            int upper = Math.max( fromPosition , toPosition );
            for( int i = itemCount-1 ; i < itemCount ; i++ )
            {
                notifyItemMoved(upper+i,lower+i+(toPosition-fromPosition));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HeaderAdapter.java

```
public class HeaderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private static final String TAG = "HeaderAdapter";
    private final RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> wrappedAdapter;

    private View header;

    public static final int HEADER_TYPE = 0x747efe;

    public HeaderAdapter( RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> wrappedAdapter , View header )
    {
        this.header = header;
        this.wrappedAdapter = wrappedAdapter;
        wrappedAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new ThisObserver());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return position == 0 ? HEADER_TYPE : wrappedAdapter.getItemViewType(position - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if( viewType == HEADER_TYPE )
        {
            return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder( header ){};
        }else
        {
            return new RecyclerView.ViewHolder( wrappedAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(parent,viewType).itemView ){};
            // I thought some kind of wrapping (hack?) like this might get 
            // around the different indexing in different Adapters, but 
            // it doesn't work, it would probably needs more 
            // information, or to be able to observe changes in 
            // the "child" ViewHolder.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if( holder.getItemViewType() != HEADER_TYPE ) wrappedAdapter.bindViewHolder( holder , position - 1 );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return wrappedAdapter.getItemCount() + 1;
    }


    private class ThisObserver extends RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver
    {

        public void onChanged() {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeChanged(1+positionStart,itemCount);
        }

        public void onItemRangeInserted(final int positionStart, final int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeInserted(1 + positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            notifyItemRangeRemoved(1 + positionStart, itemCount);
        }

        public void onItemRangeMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount) {
            fromPosition++;
            toPosition++;
            int lower = Math.min( fromPosition , toPosition );
            int upper = Math.max( fromPosition , toPosition );
            for( int i = itemCount-1 ; i < itemCount ; i++ ) notifyItemMoved(upper+i,lower+i+(toPosition-fromPosition));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about if we use decorator pattern to decorate the existing content view ?

Comment: What do you mean by "decorate the existing content view"?

Comment: decorating the view with extra items based on position in onBindViewHolder?

Comment: Sounds suspect. This behaviour should probably belong in your adapter, especially if you desire any kind of efficiency.

Comment: We are modifying the view itself which will be recycled by the recyclerview, as for inflating the decorator view we could use a view holder for that?

Comment: It really depends what you mean, and that is not a lot of detail at all.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the footer wasn't even perfect.

So you can't use this pattern for headers or footers.

When you remove items the footer wants to stick around at highest index it reached.

There are many package level variables that we don't have access to. I think the intended usage is to write the entire class in one go.

Headers and Footers probably better fit into the LayoutManager anyway, I mean, we already know what they are, they don't need "adapting"